# How to run a shell script from my published npm package

Tags: shell, npm, package

I realize this is kind of a silly question, but I'm deeply curious about how I accomplish the following.

I created a shell script for my cohort at school which builds out large project templates. I've successfully published the package to npm, but after downloading, I can't get the script to run. I'd like for users to simply download the package and run something like `$ npm project-template start`(as an example) to trigger the script.

Is this possible?

If anyone has advice, suggestions, pointers, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Its always after I ask the internet for answers that I find the answers on my own.

## Add the program to the `bin`aries object

Basically, what I needed to do was to add the command I wanted to run to the `bin` section of the `package.json`:

```
"bin": {
  "nameOfCommand": "path/to/script.sh"
}
```

The left side, `nameOfCommand`, is the name of the command that is used in your terminal

```
$ nameOfCommand args --options
```

The right side is the path to your CLI program, in this case, a bash/shell script.

[The information can be found here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm) in this article by NPM.